# How to print page title of parent and up to one child only in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a script that I got from [page title, parent tilte and grand parent title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76028/page-title-parent-tilte-and-grand-parent-title) but I want to edit it to print only **two titles** even if I'm on the 3rd or 4th subpage like this:

- Parent Page: **[Parent Title]**

  - Sub page            : **[Parent Title - Subpage Title]**

    - Second Sub page   : **[Parent Title - Subpage Title]**

I have this script on my functions.php

```
function print_page_parents($reverse = false){
  global $post;

  //create array of pages (i.e. current, parent, grandparent)
  $page = array($post->ID);
  $page_ancestors = get_ancestors($post->ID, 'page');
  $pages = array_merge($page, $page_ancestors);

  if($reverse) {
    //reverse array (i.e. grandparent, parent, current)
    $pages = array_reverse($pages);
  }

  for($i=0; $i<count($pages); $i++) {
    $output.= get_the_title($pages[$i]);
    if($i != count($pages) - 1){
      $output.= " - ";
    }
  }
    echo $output;
}
```

And I think the solution is in this part only

```
  for($i=0; $i<count($pages); $i++) {
    $output.= get_the_title($pages[$i]);
    if($i != count($pages) - 1){
      $output.= " - ";
    }
  }
    echo $output;
```

When I tried to change the `$i<count($pages)` to `$i<2` and `count($pages) - 2` in subpage it's ok but in the main page, it prints the title 2x.

```
  for($i=0; $i<2; $i++) {
    $output.= get_the_title($pages[$i]);
    if($i != count($pages) - 2){
      $output.= " - ";
    }
  }
    echo $output;
```

OUTPUT:

- ***Page Title - Page Title - (wrong)*** notice the addtional "-" at the end

  - Page Title - Sub Page Title (good)
  - - Page Page Title - Sub Page Title (good)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to test if it's a page or a sub page and then output accordingly

```
    // if sub page, change count(pages) to 2
    if ( (is_page() && $post->post_parent > 0) ) :
        for($i=0; $i<2; $i++) {
          $output.= "<span class='"."ss".$i."'>".get_the_title($pages[$i])."</span>";
          if($i != count($pages) - 2){
            $output.= " - ";
          }
        }
          echo $output;

    // if main page, default script
    elseif ( is_page() ) :
        for($i=0; $i<count($pages); $i++) {
          $output.= get_the_title($pages[$i]);
          if($i != count($pages) - 1){
            $output.= " - ";
          }
        }
          echo $output;
    endif;
```